# solana - /node_modules/@toruslabs/eccrypto/index.js: 'return' outside of function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, blockchain, wallet, solana

I am using `vue` for `solana` development.

The library I use is [@solana/wallet-adapter](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter)

error shows:

```
/node_modules/@toruslabs/eccrypto/index.js: 'return' outside of function
```

Since the example is only for `React`, it's hard for me to find the root cause of the error.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <WalletConnectButton/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ConnectionProvider, WalletProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-vue';
import { WalletAdapterNetwork } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-base';
import {
    getLedgerWallet,
    getPhantomWallet,
    getSlopeWallet,
    getSolflareWallet,
    getSolletExtensionWallet,
    getSolletWallet,
    getTorusWallet,
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets';
import {
    WalletDisconnectButton,
    WalletMultiButton,
    WalletConnectButton
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-vue-ui';
import { clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js';


export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-oskar-j1byt?file=/src/App.vue:0-906

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this helps or not, but maybe the module is missing.
`npm i @toruslabs/eccrypto`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).